# GAE images api. JPEG progressive

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, google-api, jpeg

So, i'm trying to optimize my images from Cloud Store because of using their thumbnails on website, images are tranforming in GAE. And one of the possibilities is converting JPEG images with progressive mode.

Is this possible in google images api to convert simple JPEG image to progressive mode? Or are there another library that i can use in GAE for this task?

The only solution that i can think now is upload images already in progressive mode using jpegtran lib.